# Getting errors using a trigger that is defined as if the stock is low than minimum level, insert the data into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to write a trigger that checking current stock and if the stock is lower than `minimumrequired`, especially when updated, insert data into another table.

**Product** table:

```
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    [ProductId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProductName] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [PartNumber] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [ProductLabel] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [StartingInventory] INT NOT NULL,
    [InventoryReceived] INT NOT NULL,
    [InventoryShipped] INT NOT NULL,
    [InventoryOnHand] INT NOT NULL,
    [MinimumRequired] INT NOT NULL,
) ;
```

**Alert** table:

```
CREATE TABLE alert
(
    [AlertId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProductId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ProductName] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [AlertType] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [AlertDate] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [AlertDescription] VARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

Trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [StockAlert]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER StockAlert
ON product
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO alert 
        SELECT 
            [ProductID], [ProductName], 'Low Stock', NULL,
            'There is only ' + [InventoryOnHand] + [ProductName] + ' left' 
        FROM 
            inserted
        WHERE 
            [InventoryOnHand] <= [MinimumRequired]
END
```

When I tried with the code updating values, I got the error as below.

Attempt:

```
UPDATE product 
SET InventoryOnHand = 9 
WHERE ProductId = 10
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'There is only ' to data type int

Comment: You should include the schema for the `Product` table in your question. Also consider using `cast([InventoryOnHand] as varchar(10))` in your error message.

Comment: You need to understand [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Not just in sql server but in any language you use. InventoryOnHand is (presumably) an int and it has higher precedence than the strings that you attempt to concatenate it with. So the strings are implicitly converted to int - which fails.

Comment: Spot on. When I change the type with cast([InventoryOnHand] as varchar(10)), it's working fantastically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your trigger, you should:

- **explicitly** list the columns of the target table you're inserting into (a generally accepted best practice for any SQL `INSERT` statement)
- avoid passing `NULL` for the `AlertDate` column - by **omitting** that column from the `INSERT` statement, you'll get the `DEFAULT` constraint kicking in - if you pass in `NULL`, you get `NULL` stored (which is typically not what you want)
- convert the data types when concatenating the message string (or using `CONCAT`, if your SQL Server version supports that).

Try this statement:

```
INSERT INTO alert (ProductId, ProductName, AlertType, AlertDescription)
    SELECT 
        [ProductID], [ProductName], 'Low Stock', 
        CONCAT('There is only ', [InventoryOnHand], ' ', [ProductName], ' left')
    FROM 
        inserted
    WHERE 
        [InventoryOnHand] <= [MinimumRequired]
```